# Aliased icons in Win32 Rebar control

Tags: windows, desktop-application

I added toolbar icons to my Windows desktop application. The file format is ICO with 256, 48 & 24 pixel PNGs.

The icon on the left appears with jagged edges in the Rebar menu, see image:

What could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: That is not a "ribbon", that's a Win32 Rebar control. The Ribbon control is completely different: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354408.aspx

Comment: Please repost your screenshot using the lossless PNG format and not JPEG, as JPEG compression artifacts muddy the image, making it difficult to see details such as hard-edges.

Comment: The image I posted is a PNG file saved with Sketch on Mac.

Comment: Yes, but the right side of the image (the screenshot of the Windows program) has JPEG compression artifacts.

Comment: Indeed, the image has certainly undergone JPG compression.

Comment: Does that mean the application is converting the PNGs in ICO to JPGs for use in the Rebar control? Should I try assembling ICOs with JPGs?